trace the flow from first node to last node with colors based on 1st node categories (Sankey)
I have trouble with generating the sankey diagram to trace the flow from first node to last node with colors based on 1st node categories. To understand this let take the adsl dataframe as an example,
library(tidyverse)
library(networkD3)
library(tidyCDISC)

# Load and filter the dataset
adsl <- tidyCDISC::adsl
adsl_filtered <- adsl %>% 
  rename_all(tolower) %>% 
  filter(saffl == 'Y') %>% 
  select(usubjid, agegr1, sex, race, ethnic, trt01a, bmiblgr1)

# Function to create Sankey data
create_sankey_data <- function(data, source_col, target_col) {
  data %>%
    select(usubjid, trt01a, sex, agegr1, race, ethnic, bmiblgr1) %>%
    unique() %>%
    group_by(trt01a, across(all_of(source_col)), across(all_of(target_col))) %>%
    count() %>%
    rename(source = !!sym(source_col), target = !!sym(target_col), value = n)
}

# Create Sankey data for each step
adae1 <- create_sankey_data(adsl_filtered, "trt01a", "sex")
adae2 <- create_sankey_data(adsl_filtered, "sex", "agegr1")
adae3 <- create_sankey_data(adsl_filtered, "agegr1", "race")
adae4 <- create_sankey_data(adsl_filtered, "race", "ethnic")
adae5 <- create_sankey_data(adsl_filtered, "ethnic", "bmiblgr1")

# Combine all data frames
all_adae <- bind_rows(adae1, adae2, adae3, adae4, adae5) %>% as.data.frame()

# Create a data frame for nodes
nodes <- data.frame(name = unique(c(all_adae$source, all_adae$target)))

# Create LinkGroup column based on the first node (trt01a) - propagate the group to all links
all_adae <- all_adae %>%
  mutate(LinkGroup = ifelse(is.na(trt01a), source, trt01a) )

# Match source and target names to node indices
all_adae$IDsource <- match(all_adae$source, nodes$name) - 1
all_adae$IDtarget <- match(all_adae$target, nodes$name) - 1

my_color <- 'd3.scaleOrdinal() .domain(["trt1", "trt2", "trt3"]) .range(["red", "green", "blue"])'

# Create a networkD3 Sankey plot
sankey <- sankeyNetwork(
  Links = all_adae, 
  Nodes = nodes, 
  Source = 'IDsource', 
  Target = 'IDtarget', 
  Value = 'value',
  NodeID = 'name', 
  fontSize = 15, 
  nodeWidth = 30, 
  sinksRight = TRUE, 
  nodePadding = 7,
  height = '1000px', 
  width = '2000px', 
  LinkGroup = 'target', 
  fontFamily = 'Arial',
  colourScale = my_color
)

# Display the plot
sankey

I use the above code and i get the below sankey diagram , we have 3 categories in the 1st node and i  tried to trace the subjects movement from these nodes, however i see only 2 treatment colors where actually i should have seen 3. any reason why it is not working.

